# how index is working in a function using react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, indexing, parameters, react-hooks

Below code, incrementing a quantity using onclick button. Here my doubt is how the index is working on a function increment. I could not understand the approach. Please clarify it in a simple way.

```
const Formtest = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {itemName:'item1', quantity:2, isSelected:false},
            ]);

const increment = (index) => {
        const newItems = [...items];
        newItems[index].quantity++;
        setItems(newItems);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the code that shows how `increment()` is called but looking at the code, it seems that each item, when clicked, calls `increment()` function with its index. For example, the first item will call the `increment()` as

```
onClick={() => increment(0)}
```

`0` is the index of the first item.

Inside the `increment()` function,

1. Copy (shallow) of the `items` array is created using the spread syntax

   ```
   const newItems = [...items];
   ```
2. Quantity of the item, at the `index` which `increment()` function received as an argument, is incremented

   ```
   newItems[index].quantity++;
   ```
3. Finally, state updater function is called and the new array, created in step 1, is passed to it as an argument which then updates the state asynchronously.

   ```
   setItems(newItems);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for helping it. The way of explanation is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You're using React `useState` hook which given you two things: `items` and `setItems`. You set `items` initially to a one-object array that contains this object `{itemName:'item1', quantity:2, isSelected:false}`.

Arrays in JavaScript are zero-indexed. This means that `items[0]` will give you `{itemName:'item1', quantity:2, isSelected:false}`. And `items[0].quantity` will give you `2`.

If you want to modify this object, you can't just do `items[0].quantity = items[0].quantity + 1`, because state updates in react are done though `setItems`, the second parameter you get from `useState`.

You probably have a `onClick` that passes `index` as a parameter. In our case if `index` corresponds to the first element, it will be `0`.

What `increment` function is doing is taking the `items` object and modifying it by incrementing an item at `index` position. In our case if you pass 0 as index to increment it will do the following:

```js
const increment = (index) => {
  let newItems = [...items]; // create a copy of all items, not to modify items directly
  newItems[index].quantity++; // at index position, e.g. at for first item, increment it's quantity attribute by one (++ is just a shorthand for increment by 1)
  setItems(newItems); // modify the state with new updates to the object
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, My last doubt is Whatever quantity number. Index will check the position one by one and increment the value by one with the help of index.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your newItems array is something like this

```
newItems=[
{item0},
{item1},
{item2}
]
```

`newItems[0]` will be your item0, `newItems[1]` will be your item1 and so forth.

So by passing index, you increment the quantity of that index, meaning the object that is positioned on that index in the array